Optimized algorithms for correlation based feature elimination
I have a large dataframe with close to a million rows and 2000 columns. I'm trying to do feature elimination using the correlation between the variables. The problem of course is that for a set of n features, we need the correlation between nC2 or n*(n-1)/2 combinations, making it an inherently O(n^2) operation.
So I want to know if we can optimize this using some divide and conquer strategy as follows:

calculate correlation between 20 batches of 100 columns each
eliminate the highly correlated features (threshold > 95%)
combine the remaining features (say about 1000), divide into 20 batches again
repeat the above process until we reach a fixed column threshold (that we can process together, say 200)
calculate correlation for the final time from this and drop the correlated features

I wanted to know if this method would work, or if there are further optimized methods we can use for this purpose. I also want to know if this would work for different types of correlations, like spearman, kendall, etc.
This method makes this important assumption:

if f1 and f2 are >95% correlated, f2 and f3 are also >95% correlated, then we assume f1 and f3 are also >95% correlated.

I'm not sure if there is a concrete theoretical basis for this, and would like to hear your thoughts on how to prove it for different types of correlations.
